# Characters not displaying in japanese

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013

I am using this "http://marios.com.gr/keyboard_v2/" jquery plugin in visual studio 2013. After choosing language japanese, keyboard characters are not displaying in japanese.

Comment: yes it does, try using a different browser or reset your browser configurations

Comment: I have tried in another browser but not working.

Comment: It does http://i.imgur.com/KKcpgqN.png, if this is what you're looking for then the problem is locally on your computer

Comment: If you're using Windows XP, I suggest following the steps in Method B here: http://azhagi.com/uniset.html

Comment: I am using Window 8.